# Observe changes to properties of items in a list in Polymer 1

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a property

```
  @property final List<Item> items = [
    new Item('red', false),
    new Item('green', true),
    new Item('blue', false)
  ];
```

where class `Item` looks like

```
class Item extends JsProxy {
  @reflectable String color;
  @reflectable bool checked;
  Item(this.color, this.checked);
}
```

The HTML looks like

```
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
    <label><span>{{item.color}}</span>
      <input type="checkbox"
             value="{{item.color}}"
             checked="{{item.checked::change}}">
    </label>
  </template>
```

I want to be notified when `checked` in any of the items was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An observer can be set up using the `@Observe('some.path')` annotation.
If the path contains a `.*`, the handler is called with a change record which contains the actual path of the change.

```
@Observe('items.*')
  void updateSelectedColors(Map record, [_]) {
    String path = record['path'];
    if (path == 'items' || path.endsWith('.checked')) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

`path == 'items'` applies for the initialization of the `items` property with the default value. `path.endsWidth('.checked')` ensures that the code (`// do something`) is only executed when actually the `checked` property was changed. All other changes are ignored.